# Автоматическая выгрузка заказов в личный кабинет другого пользователя 1с битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть ли возможность автоматически передавать сформированные заказы одного пользователя в личный кабинет другого в системе 1с битрикс?

Answer (score 0):

Автоматического "из коробки" нету. Но можно написать код, который через "события" будет создавать такой же заказ или присвоить другому пользователю. Еще как вариант, создать страничку, на которой при нажатии на кнопку, заказы одного пользователя будут копироваться/присваиваться другому пользователю. Еще вариант, через крон или "агента" повесить задачу на ту же манипуляцию с копированием/присвоением заказа другому пользователю.

**Справки по теме:** 
[Документация Битрикс: Агенты и их использование](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3436) 
[Документация Битрикс: События на сохранение заказа](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/sale/events/order_saved.php) 
[Википедия: Cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше реализовать логику работы менеджера и его покупателей? если допустим мне нужно чтобы сам менеджер добавлял своих клиентов в свой кабинет. Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Ну для такого рода есть разные CRM... тот же Битрикс24. А если просто БУС, то у заказов есть поле "ответственный". У меня на одном из сайтов при создании заказа присваивается ответственный - "бот". Далее в самописном личном кабинете менеджера, менеджер видит постоянно обновляющиеся заказы, когда прилетает новый заказ, то менеджер может присвоить его себе нажатием на кнопку и дальше работать с ним (печать, обработка, созвон и т.д.) - вся история заказа хранится штатными средствами Битрикс, а присвоение заказа к менеджеру через поле "ответственный" и дополнительные поля заказа, по необходимости.